# LocationSettings Dialog Appears even if GPS turn on

Tags: android, location

```
val request = LocationRequest()
    request.interval = 1000 * 60
    request.fastestInterval = 1000 * 30
    request.smallestDisplacement = 10f
    request.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(request)
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true)
    val result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
    result.addOnFailureListener {
        if (it is ResolvableApiException) {
            // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
            // by showing the user a dialog.
            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                it.startResolutionForResult(this, 1)
            } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }

        }

    }
```

Above code is for asking user to turn on location. But recently I found that some time it is asking to turn on location even if location is turned on.

**EDIT :1**
I recently found that If device have Battery saver mode ON or device location accuracy setting is LOW then this request fails with same status code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `OnFailureListener` you can additionally check is GPS on or off, then show user dialog. something like this:

```
result.addOnFailureListener {
    if (it is ResolvableApiException) {
        try {
           val lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
           val gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

           if(!gps_enabled) {
               it.startResolutionForResult(this, 1)
           } else {
               powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
               val locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(activityUnderTest.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE)

            // location mode status:
            //  0 = LOCATION_MODE_OFF
            //  1 = LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY
            //  2 = LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING
            //  3 = LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY

               if(powerManager.powerSaverMode) {
                   //show dialog to turn off the battery saver mode
               } else if (locationMode != 3){
                  //show dialog that "make sure your location accuracy is not low"
               }
           }
        } catch (sendEx: Exception) {
            // Ignore the error.
        }

    }

}
```

Remember you will need to add the following permissions in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: What should I do in else part if GPS is enabled?

Comment: @LalitJadav you can show toast that "GPS does not respond, make sure you are not in battery save mode"

Comment: What if user have clicked on "No Thanks" same response received, I want to force  gps on.

Comment: @LalitJadav in this situation you can close the app, maybe the user does not want to use GPS at this moment for another reason. You only can hint user that this app won't correctly work if GPS not respond.

Comment: Please check Edit, It only happens with some situation, even if user wants it to enable and clicks OK

Comment: What about Law_accuracy mode?

Comment: Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE this is deprecated, do you have new method

Comment: @LalitJadav you can search these subparts of the question in the google